# Android APP only needs file for first execution, and should be deleted

Tags: android, sqlite

I am creating an app that will use a SQLITE database.   When the application runs for the first time,  the database will be copied to database directory from assets.  At that point, the copy of the database in assets is really a waste of storage.  I am looking for a way to include the database in some file Android can reference and then delete. I have not found any thing approaching an automated solution.

Answer (score 1):

Assets are bundled with your APK and they are read only. You cannot delete them in your app.

If you're really worried about storage usage, consider alternative database distribution mechanisms such as downloading it over the network.

Comment: Could you provide an example of for an automated download over a network?